# Build Submodels that point to the same model

Tags: c#, asp.net, ruby-on-rails, ruby, asp.net-mvc

I used to develop in Ruby and I know this concept exists in Ruby I am trying to find out if I can do a similar thing with ASP.NET MVC 5.

I have a model `Item`. This model can have two different types `Food` and `Beverages`. In Ruby I know I could set it up to where I could call `Food.all` and `Beverage.all` rather than `Item.where(Type == "Food")`. They are all under the Item model, but I don't want to make two separate models. They need to be the same model.

Is there a way to add a Type field? Basically what I want to do is build submodels that point to the same model. I have tried Googling this, but I haven't been able to find anything. Thank you.

Comment: it sounds like you're looking for single table inheritance. http://eewang.github.io/blog/2013/03/12/how-and-when-to-use-single-table-inheritance-in-rails/

Comment: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 0):

So it seems I have figured it out. I actually saw this and assumed it was only inheriting the attributes. Looks like this is the way to implement it in ASP.NET

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application